# Why is auto-revert-mode not working?

Tags: auto-revert-mode

I have a file (my `org-mode` todo list) that I keep in sync across my machines, and I often leave it open in Emacs. Thus, I placed the following in my `.dir-locals.el` in the same folder as this file:

```
((org-mode . ((auto-revert-mode . 1))))
```

I know it has taken effect, because my modeline shows `ARev`, among others.

However, the file never auto-reverts. Even if I have been away from my machine all day, making changes on another machine and syncing them, I don't see the changes. The sync was successful though, because as soon as I try to type in that buffer, I see

```
<me>.org changed on disk; really edit the buffer? (y, n, r or C-h)
```

I can hit `r` at that point to revert the buffer, but I would rather just have that happen automatically.

Why is my file not being auto-reverted? What can I do to determine the cause of this problem?

I am running Emacs 24.4, and I have seen this behavior both on Windows 8 and on Debian Jessie.

<s>**Edit:** Forgot to check this originally, but the problem doesn't happen when I run `emacs -Q`. This means that it is caused by something in [my init file](https://github.com/501st-alpha1/emacs-init).</s>

**Edit 2:** The problem only occurs when using the `.dirs-locals` file. If I open a file, do `M-x auto-revert-mode`, and edit it elsewhere, it reverts automatically, even using my full init file.

**Edit 3:** I was mistaken: The problem **does** occur when running `emacs -Q` if I use the `.dirs-locals.el` posted above. So it is not a problem with my init file.

Comment: _"What can I do to determine the cause of this problem?"_ Start by running `emacs -q` and see if that still happens.

Comment: Right, duh. `*facepalm*` I'll report back when I've done so.

Comment: This problem does not happen with `emacs -Q`. Looks like I have some `binary search`ing to do...

Comment: Correction: the problem **does** happen with `emacs -Q`. See updated question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `t` instead of `1` as value for the mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable a minor-mode you have to use the `eval` keyword as explained in [Specifying File Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables)

> To enable or disable a minor mode in a local variables list, use the `eval` keyword with a Lisp expression that runs the mode command.

While that isn't explicitly mentioned in [Per-Directory Local Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables) it does apply here to - after all directory variables are just a convenient way of specifying file-local variables.

```
((org-mode . ((eval . (auto-revert-mode 1)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I either didn't read the instructions close enough, or the instructions I found were faulty. (I can't seem to find them again to confirm which.)